# How to correctly add a transformed variable to ggplot axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot a transformed variable (in this case an average shift value) on the y axis. For the life of me I can't understand how to get R to plot the overall result (not just the calculated sum of each day's average). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
# set up
library(tidyverse)

# example data
df <- 
tribble(
  ~Week, ~Day, ~Team, ~Sales, ~Shifts,
  "WK1", 1,    "A",     100,    1,
  "WK1", 1,    "B",     120,    1,
  "WK1", 2,    "A",     100,    1,
  "WK1", 2,    "B",     120,    1,
  "WK1", 3,    "A",     100,    1,
  "WK1", 3,    "B",     120,    1,
  "WK1", 4,    "A",     100,    1,
  "WK1", 4,    "B",     120,    1,
  "WK1", 5,    "A",     100,    1,
  "WK1", 5,    "B",     120,    1,
  "WK1", 6,    "A",     100,    1,
  "WK1", 6,    "B",     120,    1,
  "WK1", 7,    "A",     100,    1,
  "WK1", 7,    "B",     120,    1
)

# P1: y axis is not the shift average as desired. For example, Team A's shift average should be 100.
ggplot(df, aes(x = Week, y = (Sales/Shifts) )) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(.~ Team)

# P2: ggplot seems to be calculating the sum of each individual day's shift average
ggplot(df, aes(x = Week, y = (Sales/Shifts), fill = Day )) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(.~ Team)
```

The overall shift average should be
Team A: 100
Team B: 120

Comment: If you want to plot averages, you need to tell `ggplot` that somehow. The default for `geom_col` is `position = "stack"`, you plot 7 rows of data with `geom_col` and it stacks up the values for each row.

Comment: Solved! I got my plot working (actual data was a little more complicated). Thanks Gregor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend summarizing your data and giving `ggplot` the values you want to plot, rather than trying to use the graphics package to do the data manipulation for you.

```
df_avg = df %>% 
  group_by(Team, Week) %>% 
  summarize(Shift_Avg = mean(Sales / Shifts))
  ## or maybe you want sum(Sales) / sum(Shifts) ? Might be more appropriate

ggplot(df_avg, aes(x = Week, y = Shift_Avg)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_grid(~ Team)
```

[image]

Comment: This is the right approach. Try to limit how much data manipulation you're expecting `ggplot2` to do. Use `dplyr` verbs to get your data in the right format for plotting first.